# setPort() in LocalServerReciever for generating Credential Object for google api OAUTH in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use google sheets apis in my java web application. I am hosting my application in "*http://localhost:8080*" port, and I generated credentials.json file from google cloud console and added "*http://localhost:8080/home*" as redirect uri while generating the file.

this is my code to generate Credential object

```
private Credential authorize() throws Exception{
        File file = new ClassPathResource(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH).getFile();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        GoogleClientSecrets googleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        List<String> scopes = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
                .Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                    JSON_FACTORY,
                    googleClientSecrets,
                    scopes)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        LocalServerReceiver localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver
                .Builder().setPort(8080).setCallbackPath("/home").build();

        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,localServerReceiver).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }
```

As my application is being hosted on port:8080, i used 8080 as port in redirect uri, but when i run the project, it is throwing *BindException:address already in use* as port 8080 is where i host my application. when i use any other port in setPort(), 404 error is occuring. I am stuck with this for more than a day and i dont understand why i cant use 8080 port because thats where i am hosting my application.

this is the error i am getting when i tried to access google sheets from port 8888

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /home. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: Your code cannot "bind" (use) port 8080 because it is *already* in use on your machine. You will need to determine what process is using 8080 in order to decide whether you can use it for your code. Alternatively, pick another port and update the redirect. If you're running Linux you can `ss --tcp --listening --processes` to show all listening ports.  Look for either `8080` or `http-alt` and determine the process (`pid`) and then `pd -p {pid}` replacing `{pid}` with the number.

Comment: the spring boot project is running on 8080. if i use any other port lets say 8888, then how do i get data from that port 8888? and its throwing 404 error as no process is using 8888 port.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Spring but it looks as though you're setting the port in the code above to `8080`. Since it's throwing a bind error, it suggests it's trying to run a server too. You can't bind multiple processes to the same host's port.